# "Crossing someone out on a list "

Tags: word-usage

I know that it usually is "crossing someone out", like:

> I:Why is her name crossed out?
>
> Person: Because she is not going.

But my question is whether it will sound natural in "on the list" is included in a few contexts? Will it sound unnatural or natural, if not resundant in few cases...

> I: Why is her name crossed out on the list?

Comment: You've demonstrated in your first example that there are circumstances where "on the list" is redundant. Where it will not be redundant is where that phrase sets context, to tell "Person" that "I" is talking about the list. Please refine your question: what do you **actually** want to know?

Comment: Writing it 'On the list, why is her name crossed out?' makes more sense, but, English being English, "Why is her name crossed out on the list?" is what I'd expect to hear. I'd use the former in formal contexts, the latter in conversation (hence the double inverted commas).

Comment: More idiomatic is 'Why is her name crossed off the list?' // It's interesting to consider that there is a physical but also a notional list.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of *list*, the standard phrase is

> Her name was crossed off the list.

(At least, in US English.)

Definition of *to cross off* from Merriam Webster):

> to draw a line through (a name or item on a list)  Example: ***We can cross her off our list of potential donors.***

Your proposed sentence would be understood, but the one I've provided is more standard.